# Magento 2: How to upgrade Magneto version 2.2.1 to 2.3.2?

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, upgrade, composer

i want to update my Magento to v2.3.2, when i run `composer update`, i get this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.2].
    - Installation request for phpro/grumphp ^0.12.1 -> satisfiable by phpro/grumphp[v0.12.1].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.2 requires symfony/console ~4.1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v4.1.0, v4.1.0-BETA1, v4.1.0-BETA2, v4.1.0-BETA3, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0, v2.8.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0-BETA1, v2.8.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0-BETA2, v2.8.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.0-BETA3, v2.8.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.1, v2.8.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.10, v2.8.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.11, v2.8.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.12, v2.8.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.2, v2.8.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.3, v2.8.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.4, v2.8.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.5, v2.8.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.6, v2.8.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.7, v2.8.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.8, v2.8.38].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/console[v4.1.9, v2.8.38].
    - Conclusion: install symfony/console v2.8.38
```

Here is my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.3.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/composer": "@alpha",
        "ebizmarts/mailchimp-lib": "^3.0",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.2",
        "phpro/grumphp": "^0.12.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.10.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.2.2"
    },
    "config": {
        "use-include-path": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
            "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": "app/code/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "alpha",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backup your `composer.json` to easily revert your upgrade in case the upgrade fails and you want to revert your upgrade.

```
$ cp composer.json composer.json.bak
```

Enable maintenance mode, so that your update will not be able to be interrupted.

```
$ bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

First, you need to remove unused packages from your `composer.json` (`--no-update` is required here, as you are not going to install it yet, just to tell `composer` that you want to add and/or remove these packages to `composer.json`).

```
$ composer remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update
$ composer remove composer/composer magento/product-community-edition --no-update
```

Add the version `2.3.2` of `magento-product-community-edition` package to your `composer.json` (`--no-update` is required here):

```
$ composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.2 --no-update
```

Add additional packages required by Magento 2.3.2 (still, `--no-update` is required here):

```
$ composer require --dev allure-framework/allure-phpunit:~1.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.13.0 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 magento/magento-coding-standard:~1.0.0 magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework:~2.3.14 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 phpunit/phpunit:~6.5.0 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.3.1 phpunit/phpunit:~6.5.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.1 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.3.1 --sort-packages --no-update
```

Modify your `composer.json`'s autoload section to look like this:

```
....
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/",
        "Zend\\Mvc\\Controller\\": "setup/src/Zend/Mvc/Controller/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": [
            "app/code/",
            "generated/code/"
        ]
    },
},
....
```

If you have the Magento updater `<root_project>/update` (basically this updater is included), you also have to update it. These command will backup your old updater and install the updated one.

```
$ composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com magento/project-community-edition=2.3.2 update.tmp --no-install
$ mv update update.bak
$ mv update.tmp/update update
$ rm -rf update.tmp
```

Finally, install the update.

```
$ composer update
```

Clear caches and generated content.

```
$ rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/*
```

Update the database schema and data.

```
$ bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Disable maintenance mode.

```
$ bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Restart varnish (if you use one).

```
$ sudo service varnish restart
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still struggling with that use:

https://github.com/magento/composer-root-update-plugin/tree/develop/src/Magento/ComposerRootUpdatePlugin#getting-started

Read the instructions and follow.