# How to upgrade Magento 2.2.8 to 2.3.2?

Tags: magento2, error, upgrade

I am upgrading magento 2.2.8 store to 2.3.2. I have change version in composer.json  `"magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.2",` and run command composer update then get error

> Problem 1 - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition
>   2.3.2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.2]. - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.2 requires
>   dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension 3.1.2 -> satisfiable by
>   dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension[3.1.2] but these conflict with
>   your requirements or minimum-stability.

How can getout from this error? 
Thanks

Comment: Please refer to this Question, I hope this will help you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/285639/magento-2-problem-updating-magneto-v2-2-1-to-v2-3-2 also https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/question-about-migrating-from-2-28-to-latest-version-of-magento/m-p/139364/highlight/true#M2238

Comment: Follow this url to upgrade Magento2. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99813/how-to-update-magento2-from-2-0-0-to-2-0-2 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use magento script to upgrade from 2.2 to 2.3.3
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/2.3/dev/tools/UpgradeScripts/pre_composer_update_2.3.php

or at least you have to run:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.3 --no-update
composer update
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
     composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.2 --no-update

     composer update dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: how can I update it on Xampp?

Comment: Use powershell by windows.